# Sometimes the Game Center authentication handler is never called

Tags: ios, authentication, timeout, game-center, gamekit

In our iOS game, we're using Game Center to identify players and sync their data across devices using our own servers. Because Game Center identifies players, we need to know if they're authenticated, or if they've changed authentication, etc. We have a title screen that displays "Initializing Game Center..." until the authentication call returns, and only once we know who they're authenticated as (if anyone) do we go into the game.

However, a very small amount of the time (in fact, I can't reproduce it myself), the authentication handler is never called, ever. Not even after minutes of waiting. The Game Center welcome banner never displays either, so it's not that just our handler is never called, but there really is no authentication status, it seems.

So far we've implemented a 30-second timeout where if we don't hear anything from Game Center, we assume the authentication status hasn't changed, and we use your saved data. That 30 second timeout is not ideal, so I'm wondering if there is any rhyme or reason to when GC does not respond.

Here is the code that is called from our App Delegate's `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
PlayerModel *playerModel = [PlayerModel sharedPlayerModel];
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
if ([localPlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setAuthenticateHandler:)])
{
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *gkViewController, NSError *error)
    {
        if (localPlayer.authenticated)
        {
            [playerModel loadFromGameCenter];
            playerModel.hasGCStatus = TRUE;
            [playerModel sync];
        }
        else if (gkViewController)
        {
            [viewController presentViewController:gkViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Could not authenticate with Game Center");
            [playerModel unloadFromGameCenter];
            playerModel.hasGCStatus = TRUE;
            [playerModel sync];
        }
    };
}
else
{
    [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (localPlayer.authenticated)
        {
            [playerModel loadFromGameCenter];
            playerModel.hasGCStatus = TRUE;
            [playerModel sync];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Could not authenticate with Game Center");
            [playerModel unloadFromGameCenter];
            playerModel.hasGCStatus = TRUE;
            [playerModel sync];
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure localPlayer isn't nil ?
Do you have any guess on with iOS version the handler isn't called ? Is it final version or a beta one ?
If iOS 7 beta, fill a bug report to Apple.
Are you sure to not setting the completion handler to nil otherwhere ?

Comment: What does happen? Does it log the error, or nothing? It would be good to know what the output is, when the game center didn't work.

Comment: @Gougou this has been happening on iOS 6 to the best of my knowledge, not beta versions.

Comment: @ViktorLexington nothing happens at all. No errors logged or anything.

Answer (score 3):

I had this experience during testing on one of our games on the sandbox server, there really was no notification or authentication handler call sometimes, then it would just work a half hour later.

We summised that it was due to Apple's server end as we never encountered this problem outside of the Game Center sandbox.

Sorry that the explanation is a little vague and there's nothing concrete that you can do. But it's not your code. It's on the end that you cannot control.

Comment: This is probably the best answer available. I'm not going to accept it, in hopes that there is another answer out there (the bounty has expired anyway). Thanks anyway.

Comment: No worries, sometimes apple's services feel like they're in flux and there's no satisfactory way to satisfactory way to catch all the problems it causes.

Comment: @RuddZwolinski do you have this problem on main game center server (e.g. not a sandbox)? Because I have very same problem, except that in my case this is not a random event. It happens when I cancel login form, then pop from this view controller to previous one. And then call authentication once more. On the second time I don't receive any response. I don't know what to do =/ I'm on a sandbox game center.

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to `GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName` which should notify after authentication.  This at least may infer a missing message.

It is possible that the problem is at Apple's servers.  You could eliminate that by running a wireshark trace from a network proxy that your iPhone uses.  If its only seen from other people's phones, then maybe log the network connectivity and reachability they experience to correlate if particular network events on their end are to blame.

Also its worth logging the `NSErrors` as part of your code in case its trying to tell you something that is being overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same problem here which we realized only happened for some people on wifi.  It turns out GameCenter requires a ridiculous number of firewall allowances to work: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944
We believe the issue is that some networks block these ports which then cause the call to never respond.